# Where can I find a solution to a problem I encountered in MS Publisher?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have encountered a very annoying "thing" in MS Publisher (probably not a bug, but some sort of hidden setting) which prevents me from continuing to work.

I have tried googling what to do but no one else seems to be having the same problem.

I tried asking on Super User ([MS Office 2013 - Publisher - Cannot use most fonts](https://superuser.com/questions/1255065/ms-office-2013-publisher-cannot-use-most-fonts)) but the question only got 2 views and I am afraid both of those views were just me on different devices.

I have tried to find MS Office help forums but at every one of these forums it takes a couple of days before you get an answer.

I need to figure out a solution to this problem quickly since I need to finish my work... please help. What should I do?

Comment: If you need help fast please contact microsoft support

Comment: *"asked 36 mins ago"* ... you _could_ give the people more time ... (your timing concerns are no matter for Stack Exchange)

Comment: Don't expect a community of volunteers that spend their free time answering questions feel responsible for your planning issues. If what ever you needed to do was so time critical, you should have started earlier ... also note that in large parts of the world it is weekend now, which means we get much less traffic.

Answer (score 7):

It's the right site. I don't think there's any better site - but if it was easy, well, you'd know the answer or someone might answer it quickly. If it's hard, well...

It does take a while sometimes for the *right* person to come across the answer - even with say a bounty.

That said, your question could probably be better and I've made a few improvements - I've added an animated gif (made with licecap) from your video showing the issue in the question itself and removed some extraneous bits. This should make it easier for someone to tell *at a glance* what your issue is.

Other than that - there's not much to do but wait. There isn't even a sister site that does windows stuff.